# Synchronizing Serial Port Reading/Writing

Tags: c#, synchronization, serial-port

I'm attempting to write a c# program in Visual Studio 2010 that communicates with a micro controller via a serial connection. I can read and write to the port just fine, I am just unsure of how to have the send method wait until all of the data from the previous send command has been received before it executes. I have implemented the data received event handler such that it determines when the proper amount of data that had been requested has been received on the serial port. I just need to know how to cause that to tell the send method the port is free.

I had planned on using a mutex, but I believe the problem is not due to multi-threading. The same thread is sending strings out on the serial port one after another and the data being received in response to the first request is conflicting with the second request.

Also, if the communication is being done by one thread, would having that thread wait cause the data received event handler to not execute?

(both methods are in the same class)

My send data method:

```
//method for sending data
public void send(String s)
{

    sp.Write(s + "\r");
}
```

My data received event handler:

```
//data received event handler
private void dataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string tmp;
    tmp = sp.ReadExisting();

    //put all received data into the read buffer
    readBuffer += tmp;

    //add various flag checks to determine end of transmission
    if (firmwareFlag)
    {
        if (readBuffer.EndsWith("\n"))
        {
            firmwareFlag = false;

            //trigger event to tell object owner data is ready
            dataReady(this, new CustomEventArgs(readBuffer, "firmware"));
            readBuffer = "";

        }
    }
    else if (parameterFlag)
    {
        if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(readBuffer, "K90", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            parameterFlag = false;

            dataReady(this, new CustomEventArgs(readBuffer, "parameters"));
            readBuffer = "";

        }
    }
    else
    {
        dataReady(this, new CustomEventArgs(readBuffer, null));
        readBuffer = "";
    }

}
```

Comment: It turns out I was misinterpreting how data is sent and received on the serial port. Data that is sent and received never conflicts with each other as the sent messages and received messages are buffered on both the micro controller side and the pc side. The framework of the serial communication between the two sources sorts out all of the details. My problem was with how I processed the data received.

Comment: Err, no.  It is true that send and receive don't conflict, but the reason is not buffering.  Send and receive use completely separate pins, so a serial port supports full-duplex.

Answer (score 0):

I would use just a bool variable in the class, and a timer. When timer ticks, you check that bool and send the data if it is allowed.

```
boolean isAllowed;
DispatcherTimer tmr1;
//...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on the past and I solved this way:

I added SendAndWaitResponse method which receives the buffer to be sent by the port, the expected lenght of the response, a timeout in seconds(just in case), and a callback, when the expected response has been received:

```
//System.IO.Ports.SerialPort port; 
        //port.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
        void SendAndWaitResponse(String buffer, int expectedLenght, int timeoutInSeconds, Action<String> callback)
        {
            TimeSpan _timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, timeoutInSeconds);

            //may not be necesary
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(buffer) && buffer != "" && port != null)
            {
                //Remove current dataReceived event handler, as we will manually manage it for now, will restore later!
                this.port.DataReceived -= port_DataReceived;
                if (!this.port.IsOpen) this.port.Open(); // open the port if it was closed
                this.send(buffer); // send buffer, changed port.write(buffer) so it now usses your own send

                DateTime startToWait = DateTime.Now; //start timeout
                bool isTimeout = false;
                int totalRead = 0;
                String read = "";

                while (!(isTimeout) && totalRead < expectedLenght)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        if (port.BytesToRead > 0)
                        {
                            read += (char)this.port.ReadByte();
                            totalRead++;
                            //you can add a System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(int); if all bytes come in parts
                        }
                    } while (port.BytesToRead > 0);
                    isTimeout = (DateTime.Now.Subtract(_timeout) >= startToWait);
                }

                this.port.DataReceived += port_DataReceived; // restore listener
                callback(read); //invoke callback!!!
            }
        }
```

Comment: I haven't run this code! Let me know if it doesn't work, and will fix it. (I don't have any serial device to test it atm).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if there are bytes with out send to the device (bytes in write buffer), so you can read BytesToWrite property.


[SerialPort.BytesToWrite Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.ports.serialport.bytestowrite.aspx)